# Jira JQL, find issues that have changes status

Tags: jira, jql

Could you help me to find a right JQL expression:

I want to find issues that changed status more then 7 days ago. I use the next JQL:

*...status in ("X") AND status changed to "X" before startOfDay(-7)*

But there is one problem: a status can be changed some times but I need just last change.
But this JQL does not consider this condition and returns issues that changed status yesterday (because the first change was 1 month ago, for example).
What the condition help to find only last changes of status?

Comment: So if you add to the JQL "and status = "x", wouldn't you cover most of the cases (sure, there are some pretty rare cases that will also apply, but still)

Comment: It is not so rare case, for example Bugs often returns to previous state (to reFix). 
Or if we write TestCaces and Lead check it he can return issue to fix for some marks. 
As a result - there are some transferes to status X, but I need control only last changeing.

Comment: Well, I agree - how rare it is depends on your context. Anyway, that's the best I could come up with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem. Let's think logically ;) We need to catch issues which changed status to "X" before and did not changed it AFTER. So let's play with logic BEFORE and AFTER:

...AND status changed to "X" before startOfDay(-7) **AND NOT status CHANGED TO "X" AFTER startOfDay(-6)**